# How could an undefined variable throw a type error?

Tags: javascript

I have a user who is getting the error

```
TypeError: a is undefined
```

I'm confused how this can happen. Won't trying to access an undefined variable throw a reference error? In what situation could it throw a type error?

Comment: Maybe you tried to call `a`. If it's undefined, you'd get a type error. Show us the code that throws this!

Comment: @Bergi I wish I could see it. I don't have access to that code; it is from another team. I just saw the email that said the user was receiving it and it really piqued my curiosity about possible scenarios which could cause it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @jgillich in his answer, the following code produces a `TypeError` on an `undefined` object.

```
> a
ReferenceError: a is not defined
> var a;
> a.x
TypeError: a is undefined
```

To understand why, we can refer to ECMAScript 5.1 spec section [11.2.1 Property Accessors](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1). We are interested in step 5

> 5. Call CheckObjectCoercible(*baseValue*).

In our example, *baseValue* is the value of the reference `a`. That means *baseValue* is `undefined`.

`CheckObjectCoercible` is defined in [section 9.10](http://es5.github.io/#x9.10)

> The abstract operation CheckObjectCoercible throws an error if its argument is a value that cannot be converted to an Object using ToObject. It is defined by Table 15:

And we can see in Table 15 that a `TypeError` is thrown for `undefined` and `null` values.

So the reason why we have a `TypeError`instead of a `ReferenceError` is, as usual, because the spec says so!

There are other ways to obtain a `TypeError` on `undefined`, notably [ToObject](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9) also throws a `TypeError` for `undefined`.

These three lines of code produce `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`:

```
Object.defineProperties({}, undefined);
Object.prototype.toLocaleString.call(undefined);
Object.prototype.valueOf.call(undefined);
```

Though this time the message is a bit clearer.

Also invoking directly on `undefined` produces `TypeError: undefined has no properties`

```
undefined.foo();
undefined.x;
```

All of this was tested using Firefox 33.0a2 (Aurora).

Answer (score 2):

```
> a
ReferenceError: a is not defined
> var a;
> a.x
TypeError: a is undefined
```

Comment: What browser? Chrome gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" EDIT: Got it in FireFox

Comment: Ah. Cool. Thank you. Why doesn't that throw a ReferenceError though?

Comment: @thomas See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589391/difference-typeerror-and-referenceerror

Comment: @Vache Do you know why this would throw a reference error?

Comment: @KyleNeedham Why would the error say that it cannot read `x of undefined`. It makes it sound as though the object of which `x` is a property is undefined. Which it isn't..

Comment: @thomas It is undefined. It's declared, but undefined.

Comment: @thomas I posted a new answer, it was getting to long for comments!